# Rails Thread.current[] & thread safety

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thread-safety

So there I was, right. Just looking through some code, studying bits and pieces when all of a sudden, my ocular receptors were assaulted by the unfamiliar. I was like:

> What!!! What's that all about!

Anyway, what I saw was ([source](https://github.com/rilian/devise-doorkeeper-cancan-api-example/blob/master/app/controllers/api/base_controller.rb#L23-L25)):

```
def authenticate_user!
  if doorkeeper_token
    Thread.current[:current_user] = User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id)
  end

  # ...
end
```

So after looking at it for a while, thinking:

> Wtf is this `Thread.current[]` insanity? Is this even necessary? What's it even trying to do?

It seemed to me it was kind of like wearing a baseball cap backwards: You may look pretty f'ing cool but that sun glare is winning. I then decided to Google around, read some articles and some SO.

None seemed to concisely answer my question: **Given the context of the code, would it not be the same as:**

```
def authenticate_user!
  if doorkeeper_token
    @current_user = User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id)
  end

  # ...
end
```

If not, what situation/scenario is it useful/protecting against?

I hope you enjoyed my story and want to contribute an awesome ending.

Comment: I submitted an edit removing all the extra details. I would suggest not including such a story with your question. (1) Could lead to down votes or flags for being "off topic" at the surface. (2) Deters others from answering, because the question is masked in such a long story.

Comment: @HunterStevens I respectfully disagree and do not appreciate the edit. It is not a "long" story by any means and a bit of levity goes a long way to help absorption of information. See http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/ for a perfect example of this.

Comment: Hear! Hear! for rolling back idiotic edits. Ever read George Orwell's 1984?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the author:

> I use Thread to store current user to be able transparently
>   authenticate user and extend this later. Currently this code gives
>   priority to token-based authentication via Doorkeepr, and you can
>   extend it to any other algorithm. I am not a big fan of Devise and did
>   not want to use the token-based authentication strategy it provides.
>
> Once you write user info inside Thread.currrent[:current_user], any
>   other service can read it independently and use for whatever purposes
>   it is needed. For example, as i mentioned above, checking
>   authorization, logging who did the events happening in the system, etc
>
> as for writing it to `@current_user`, i am not sure it will be
>   accessible in all contexts. But i have not really checked this

Reference: https://github.com/rilian/devise-doorkeeper-cancan-api-example/issues/1#issuecomment-143479288

Comment: For me, logging who did something is a use case. For example, if this is set in a controller/request context, you know that some updates where originated by some authenticated user. But if someone enters the Rails console and change something, this :current_user is not available.

Answer (score 5):

There are different bulletin boards on which you can pin information.  The bulletin board where `local variables` are posted is hidden behind hedges and cannot be seen by the views who live in the next yard:

```
current_user = User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id)
```

The bulletin board where `@variables` are posted is nailed to the top of a ladder, so the views have an unobstructed view of the @variables over the tops of the hedges:

```
@current_user = User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id)
```

But other methods, which live in classes across the street, cannot see the @variables posted on the bulletin board on top of the ladder because a row of trees is in the way.

`Thread variables`, such as:

```
Thread.current[:current_user] = User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id)
```

launch a kite, which flies higher than the trees, and the variables posted on the kite can be seen by the methods that live across the street.

Why not create a ruby `global variable`, e.g. $current_user, instead?  Because then requests initiated simultaneously by different users will write to the same global variable, potentially screwing things up.

> Given the context of the code

There's not enough context to tell why a (thread) global variable is needed.

Comment: Thanks @7stud, for context you can view the entire project via the source link in the question. The `Thread.current[:current_user]` is used only in that class. It's referenced nowhere else in the project which made me think that `@current_user` would be sufficient. Very nice analogy and continuation to my epic thread safe adventure.

Comment: @EasyCo, The example also has this line: `return if current_user`, yet current_user is not defined anywhere, so it appears to me that the example pulls in other code from somewhere, and maybe that other code looks at Thread.current?

Comment: It's defined as a method right below it where is returns `Thread.current[:current]`

Comment: @EasyCo, Ha!  I must have misspelled it.  Nope.  When I search the repository for current_user, it won't show the method definition--even though it's there.

Comment: @EasyCo, devise calls current_user all over the place.  Isn't doorkeeper supposed to work in conjunction with devise?  I think the doorkeeper example is trying to ensure that devise operates in a thread safe manner.